# Determin Type of Input - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am needing to determine the type of an element, possibly identified by the `id` property of it.

For example, in the following form...

```
<form id='my-form'>
  <input type='text' id='title' />
  <textarea id='comment'></textarea>
</form>
```

I would like to have a way to identify that `$('#title')` is a text box.

After some searches, I tried some thing like this, but it returns `undefined`.

```
$('#title').type
```

But some thing like this seems to work, I don't know why...

```
$('#my-form :input').each( function() {
  alert(this.type);
} );
```

The above will give `text` and `textarea` I guess. But when I use the first, it gives undefined.

given an ID of an element, how can I find the type of it.

Thank in advance.

Comment: You could use `$('#title')[0].type`

Comment: @Ian Works great, but you hadn't put it as an answer. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` is a normal tag, you should use:

```
$('#my-form input').each( function() {
  alert(this.type);
});
```

This will return undefined:

```
$('#title').type
```

Because `$("#title")` is a jQuery object and `type` is a property of HTML Element. You can get HTML Element from jQuery object like this:

```
$('#title').get(0).type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type  of the element  by writing

```
$("#target").attr('type');
```

or use

```
$("#target").get(0).tagName  // return tag name like INPUT,TEXTAREA ..etc
```

Comment: And what about `textarea`?

Comment: As I commented tagName returns in Capital letters,please be aware.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if($('#title').is('input')){
    alert('title in an input element')
} else if($('#title').is('textarea')){
    alert('title in an textarea)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#title').attr('type') ;
```

OR

```
$('#title').prop('type');
```